# Simplifying algebraic sum with binomial coefficients

Tags: combinatorics, algebra-precalculus, binomial-coefficients, binomial-theorem

I need to simplify this expression further:

$$ \sum_{m=1}^N (-1)^{m-1} m \binom{N}{m} $$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint:  Recall that $$(1 - x)^N = \sum\limits_{m = 0}^N (-1)^m \binom{N}{m}x^m.$$

What happens if you differentiate both sides?

Comment: I think you made an error there; you can't move the $x^{m-1}$ from inside the sum on the left to the right. So it should read $$\sum_{m=1}^N (-1)^{m-1} m \binom{N}{m} x^{m-1} = (1 - x)^{N-1} N.$$  What can you do to get rid of the $x^{m-1}$ term on the left?

Comment: @Tiana, It's okay: You can set $x = 1$ on both sides.

Answer (score 1):

Use the identity
$$
\binom{N}{m}\binom{m}{1} =\binom{N}{1}\binom{N-1}{m-1}
=N\binom{N-1}{m-1}
$$
to get that 
$$
\sum_{m=1}^N (-1)^{m-1} m \binom{N}{M}
=\sum_{m=1}^N (-1)^{m-1}N\binom{N-1}{m-1}
=N\sum_{u=0}^{N-1} (-1)^{u}\binom{N-1}{u}=0
$$
by considering the binomial expansion of $(1-1)^{N-1}$.

Comment: @Tiana $0=(1-1)^{N-1}=\sum_{u=0}^{N-1} (-1)^{u}\binom{N-1}{u}$

Comment: @Tiana Yes it does.

Comment: @Tiana No the sum is still zero.